# createFreezeAccountInstruction causing sendTransaction to fail

Tags: spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter

I'm trying to send a `createFreezeAccountInstruction` using `@solana/spl-token` and `@solana/wallet-adapter-react` but I keep getting a general `sendTransaction` failed error after signing the transaction in Phantom.

Here's a code example of my function:

```
    const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();

    const revokeFreezeAuthority = async () => {

        if (!publicKey) {
            alert('Wallet not connected');
            return;
        }

        const mintPubKey = new PublicKey('XXXX'); // removed here but verified I'm using correct one

        const revokeFreezeAuthorityTransaction = new Transaction().add(
            createFreezeAccountInstruction(mintPubKey, mintPubKey, publicKey)
        );

        const tx = await sendTransaction(revokeFreezeAuthorityTransaction, connection);
     
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong mint public key twice. You have to pass the account PDA first as well to sign the transaction.

```
createFreezeAccountInstruction(account, mint, authority, multiSigners?, programId?): TransactionInstruction

Example:
createFreezeAccountInstruction(
          tokenAccount,//Token Account
          mint, //Mint account
          publicKey  //Mint freeze authority
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to revoke the freeze authority, as your code implies with `revokeFreezeAuthority`, you'll need to use the `createSetAuthorityInstruction`, ie:

```
createSetAuthorityInstruction(
    mint,
    publicKey,
    AuthorityType.FreezeAccount,
    null,
)
```

More documentation at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/d4351c94cbcd8417262c11d201dcb2568057f204/token/js/src/instructions/setAuthority.ts#L61